# Using R to recode data into the existing column

Tags: r

I have a column called, `CONDITIONALAPPROVAL` and it's filled with a lot of the letter, `N`.  I'd like to recode all these `N`s to `0`.  Below is the code I'm using but when I print the column after only `<NA>`s are present.

```
attach(my_data)
my_data$CONDITIONALAPPROVAL[my_data$CONDITIONALAPPROVAL=='N'] <- 0
my_data$CONDITIONALAPPROVAL
```

It seems simple but it's not working and when I output that column it's just `<NA>`s where there should be `0`s.

Comment: Did you get any warning message? Is your `my_data$CONDITIONALAPPROVAL` a `factor`? You might want to try converting it to character if so: `my_data$CONDITIONALAPPROVAL <- as.character(my_data$CONDITIONALAPPROVAL)`

Comment: Is the column in character class?

Comment: You don't need to `attach` your data if your going to use the name of your data.frame in each call.

Comment: It's almost certainly a factor which doesn't have 0 in its levels. If you coerce to character first (`df$x <- as.character(df$x)`), it should work fine. Also see `dplyr::recode`, which is nice for this purpose, or `switch`, upon which it's based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the variable a string first (as it is, it seems to be a factor):

```
my_data$CONDITIONALAPPROVAL <- as.character(my_data$CONDITIONALAPPROVAL)
```

Then:

```
my_data$CONDITIONALAPPROVAL[my_data$CONDITIONALAPPROVAL=='N'] <- 0
```

And if need be / relevant, convert to numeric:

```
my_data$CONDITIONALAPPROVAL <- as.numeric(my_data$CONDITIONALAPPROVAL)
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(my_data, key = "CONDITIONALAPPROVAL")[
    , CONDITIONALAPPROVAL :=  as.character(CONDITIONALAPPROVAL)
        ][("N"), CONDITIONALAPPROVAL := "0"]
```

Comment: Just curious, is there any advantage to setting the column as key instead of specifying it in the last step?

Comment: @rosscova It would be a bit faster in subsequent runs

Comment: @rosscova, unless you're going to do repeated subset/join operations, no.